# Mail Sending problem

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

```
public class MailEx {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        String userName = "abc@gmail.com";          
        String password = "123";            
        String hostName = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String fromName = "Splendore Bkk";
        String to[] = {"xyz@gmail.com"};

        System.out.println("to.length::"+to.length);

        Properties props = new Properties();
        String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"; 

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");     
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        System.out.println("to.length:sadfsadfds:"+to.length);
        // Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message1 = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set the RFC 822 "From" header field using the
        // value of the InternetAddress.getLocalAddress method.
        message1.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName,fromName));

        Address[] addresses = new Address[to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++) {
            Address address = new InternetAddress(to[i]);               
            addresses[i] = address;
            // Add the given addresses to the specified recipient type.
            message1.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to[i]));
        }       
        // Set the "Subject" header field.
        message1.setSubject("Testing");

        // Sets the given String as this part's content,
        // with a MIME type of "text/plain".
        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
        mbp.setContent("Hii from cc", "text/html");
        mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
        message1.setContent(mp);
        message1.saveChanges();

        // Send message
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(hostName,userName,password);
        transport.sendMessage(message1,addresses);
        transport.close();


    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

I getting the Error ....

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4ea
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ..\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\javamail.providers (The system cannot find the file specified)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/mail/util/LineInputStream
    at javax.mail.Session.loadProvidersFromStream(Session.java:928)
    at javax.mail.Session.access$000(Session.java:174)
    at javax.mail.Session$1.load(Session.java:870)
    at javax.mail.Session.loadResource(Session.java:1084)
    at javax.mail.Session.loadProviders(Session.java:889)
    at javax.mail.Session.<init>(Session.java:210)
    at javax.mail.Session.getInstance(Session.java:249)
    at com.test.MailEx.main(MailEx.java:41)
```

So can u  tell me what's the problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid `DEBUG` warnings, create files `javamail.providers, javamail.address.map, javamail.default.address.map, javamail.default.providers` under

```
 (Program Files)\Java\jdk1.6.0\jre\lib\
```

folder.

About the error, `NoClassDefFoundError`, well you simply didn't add JavaMail to your classpath. If you are using Eclipse, right click project, follow Build Path ≥ Add Libraries or something like that and add javamail's `jar` file (which you should locate under your `lib/` folder) to classpath of your project.

Comment: thanks for the ans but i have added 2 jar for sending mail.. i.e mail.jar and activation.jar

Answer (score 0):

I fix it , look how my code is writing

must to approve before in your google account
**Set Allow less secure apps** to ***ON***
example how i did it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64023055/2347210
Use javax.mail version 1.4.7

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public void SendEmail() throws Exception {
String EmailUsername = "MYMAIL@gmail.com";
String PasswordUsername = "SomePassword";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(EmailUsername, PasswordUsername);
        }
    });

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EmailUsername));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("Example@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("This is the Qa test!");
        message.setText("this is the report");
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Message Sent!");

    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See this this have solution

[my ans check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12744169/sending-mail-using-javamail-not-working/20879361#20879361)

this is having desired solution for your problem

Hope that will help.