# Sending mail using javamail not working

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send and email using my gmail address.
I set debug to true and this is what I get.

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.1
DEBUG: not loading file: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javamail.providers
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javamail.providers (No such file or directory)
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: !anyLoaded
DEBUG: not loading resource: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: not loading file: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javamail.address.map
DEBUG: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javamail.address.map (No such file or directory)

DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.1
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 465, isSSL true
```

And then I does just nothing, no error/warning/....

I'm using these settings :

```
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.debug=true
mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
mail.smtp.user=MyOwnUserName@gmail.com
mail.smtp.password=MyOwnPassword
mail.transport.protocol=smtp
mail.smtp.port=465
mail.disable=false
mail.verbose=true
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
```

I tried these examples :

1. http://adfblogs.blogspot.be/2012/01/sending-e-mail-from-adf-application.html
2. [Send email using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649014/send-email-using-java)

All the same problem. And I'm 100% sure my password and emailadress is correct.

Edit:
My code (the same as in the first link)
nitialContext ic = new InitialContext();
            Session session = (Session) ic.lookup("mail/SugarCRMMailSession");

```
        Properties props = session.getProperties();

        String  to = emailID;

        String mailhost = props.getProperty("mail.smtp.host");
        String user = props.getProperty("mail.smtp.user");
        String password = props.getProperty("mail.smtp.password");
        String protocol = props.getProperty("mail.transport.protocol");

        String authorization = props.getProperty("mail.smtp.auth");
        String mailDisabled = props.getProperty("mail.disable");
        String verboseProp = props.getProperty("mail.verbose");
        String debugProp = props.getProperty("mail.debug");

        boolean sentDisabled = false;
        if(mailDisabled.equals("true"))
            sentDisabled = true;

        if(!sentDisabled){

            boolean auth = false;
            if(authorization.equals("true"))
                auth = true;

            boolean verbose = false;
            if(verboseProp.equals("true"))
                verbose = true;

            String mailer = "smtpsend";

            if(debugProp.equals("true"))
                session.setDebug(true);
            else
                session.setDebug(false);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom();      
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to, false));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setContent(text, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");      
            msg.setHeader("X-Mailer", mailer);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport(protocol);

            try {
                t.connect(mailhost, user, password);
                t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
            } finally {
                    t.close();
            }

             System.out.println("\nMail was sent successfully.");
        }else{
             System.out.println("Mail Sending is disabled.");
        }
```

Comment: Read this carefully http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#debug

Comment: Is there a chance that you are behind firewall?

Comment: @AlexR telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 works fine so there shouldn't be any network problems.

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov I suppose you wanted that I tested the telnet? Since debug is already happening

Comment: @user1109719 When debug is enabled and properly configured it should print SMTP protocol logs - read them and you'll find your problem. Otherwise you have a network problem or may be SSL negotiation problem

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov After more research I found that indeed there are some problems regarding the SSL negotiation. It's solved now. Thanks!

Comment: Well i got the solution for this. read my reply for that i am sure that is only the solution is

Comment: I am getting the same issue. What helped you exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here this is perfect solution for your problem download Mail api jar form here

[Api mail providers for gmail](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjavamailsmtp142jar.htm)

and just go to Windows --> Preferencs --> Java --> Installed JRES -->

and what ever JRE You are using just select it and EDIT and then add that external jar into that JRE and Click okey then Compiler will able to load that jar file. hence the error will get resolved.

Try it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem I faced was with SSL in our  network. Fyi I used javamail on a WebLogic Server.

Comment: But have u got solution for that? what is the real solution for that but ya this solution is worked for me. have u tried.?

Comment: Yes, our network administrator modified our firewall if I'm not mistaking.

Comment: okey so there is problem with that. and which port u are working in for this?

Comment: May be if u try with Port 25 then there wont be need of changing firewall settings. i think so because same issue i was facing and i got that solution with out changing firewall.

Comment: Link doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Link is dead, but downloading *.jars is an old style of getting deps. Consider using Apache ivy, or gradle, for lib jar dependancies, and then use the maven repository online to find the code to download them.

Comment: for those who have ssl issue with such cases I have tried the github repo [link](https://github.com/escline/InstallCert) detailed usage can be seen on the readme of the repo. It will basically retrieve the certificate from the the host:port you are trying to reach and add it to your jvm/jre certificate path.