# No provider for smtp inside EMR

Tags: java, email, sbt

I'm trying to send an email on completion of the EMR job. I have used libraryDependencies += "com.sun.mail" % "javax.mail" % "1.6.2" in my sbt dependencies.

I tested the email sending in local and it works fine but the same job fails in the EMR job with the below exception:

```
20/11/21 04:28:12 WARN mail: expected resource not found: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No provider for smtp
    at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:545)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:744)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:725)
    at javax.mail.Session.getTransport(Session.java:782)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:249)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at util.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:44)
    at util.EmailUtil.sendMail(EmailUtil.java:59)
    at com.here.places.rule.testing.EmailTester$.main(EmailTester.scala:16)
    at com.here.places.rule.testing.EmailTester.main(EmailTester.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:706)
```

The code used is `
public class EmailUtil {
public static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String
body){
try
{
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
//set message headers
msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");

```
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(toEmail));
        msg.setReplyTo(InternetAddress.parse(toEmail));
        msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
        msg.setText(body, "UTF-8");

        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
        System.out.println("Message is ready");
        Transport.send(msg);

        System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void sendMail() {
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "***");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    sendEmail(session, "***","SimpleEmail Testing Subject", "SimpleEmail Testing Body");
}
```

}`

Comment: Try Amazon Simple Email Service located [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/example_code/ses).

Comment: Thanks. I will try Amazon Simple Email Service. But still, I want to know what exactly is the problem here. I logged into the data node and pinged the smtp host and it was successful. Also, telnet host-name 25 also successful. This confirms that there is no network issue.

Comment: I can only refer you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12744169/2970947).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The application is build using SBT and used the below merge strategy.

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

The fat jar created didn't have the necessary META_INF files from the javax.mail jar and it was causing an issue. For testing purpose, I manually copied the META-INF files from javax.mail jar to the fat jar and it worked.

Comment: Why info is not supplied of how this issue was actually solved? How does the SBT looks like?