# Attempting to implement sending an email through SMTP in Java, but get the error "AUTH LOGIN failed"

Tags: java, email, outlook, smtp

I have been banging my head against my desk for the past couple of days trying to figure out why I keep getting the following errors when attempting to implement Java code for sending an email through my company's Outlook server:

```
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN failed
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 5.7.0 authentication failed
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:932)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:843)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:748)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:388)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:195)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

Here is the code in question:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.activation.*;

public class SendEmail3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Login e = new Login();

        String host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
        String port = "465";
        final String userName = e.getEmailUser();
        final String password = e.getEmailPassword();
        String toAddress = "first.last@email";
        String subject = "TEST";
        String message = "This is a test email";

        // sets SMTP server properties
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        properties.put("mail.debug", "true");
        // properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.user", userName);
        properties.put("mail.password", password);

        // creates a new session with an authenticator
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
            }
        };
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, auth);

        // creates a new e-mail message
        Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName));
        InternetAddress[] toAddresses = { new InternetAddress(toAddress) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddresses);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");

        // creates multi-part
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
        msg.setContent(multipart);

        // sends the e-mail
        Transport.send(msg);

    }

}
```

The error is triggered at **Transport.send(msg)**. Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you print out e.getEmailUser() and e.getEmailPassword() and verify that they're correct

Comment: I know for a fact that e.getEmailPassword() is correct (unless my Outlook password isn't the same as my Windows 7 password, which means I was wrong all along). e.getEmailUser() is "first.last@company.com", but I am starting to think that might have to be written differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`535` code stands for bad username or password.

Make sure your email user and password are correct by debugging this code.

Another tip is to login to mail via web or maybe try to change password to mail.

Answer (score 5):

You need to visit https://myaccount.google.com ,go  secure and change  acces for less secure app.gmail.smtp needed latest version autharization thats why it didn work.

Comment: my example how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/64023055/2347210