# getting "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" this error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

Getting error on sending mail.Even though the exact properties inside application.properties worked few months back.

This is the properties to configure mail sending inside application.properties

```
mail.enable=true
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.username=abc@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=**************
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465

mail.smtp.port=2525

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true 
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=false

spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false

support.email=abc@gmail.com
```

How can I reconfigure this? I tried by following specific password pattern. Would appreciate any sort of suggestions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347269/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-ac

Comment: gone through this and tried also. It didn't work.

Comment: Get rid of all the [socket factory settings](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), then post the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).

Answer (score 8):

**For Gmail**

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=example@gmail.com
spring.mail.password= Your Generated App Password (not your Gmail Account Password)
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```

---

How to generate your App Password? [Click Here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833)

Comment: Hi I have added 2FA on my google account and used the app password it's still not working. Any idea why ?

Answer (score -2):

go to https://myaccount.google.com/security

on the section Less secure app access select **Turn on access** and click on **Allow less secure apps: OFF**

My `application.properties` looks like this:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.mail=DEBUG
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=enter_here_your_email
spring.mail.password=enter_here_your_password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
```