# How to send message JavaMail on GMAIL?

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I turned on IMAP in gmail settings. I dont have two-factor auth, only with single password.

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=${mymail}
spring.mail.password=${emailPassword}
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimout=5000
```

```
    public void sendMessage(){
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo("mymail@gmail.com");
        message.setSubject("hello world");
        message.setText("Hello world \n Spring boot");
        emailSender.send(message);

    }
```

```
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        emailService.sendMessage();
    }
```

What I am doing wrong?
exception:
`javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.`

Comment: Try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347269/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-ac

Comment: This issue is answered [here in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347269/javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception-535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-ac)